# jQuery + Ajax - kills Safari browser in a few clicks

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

I'd appreciate any suggestions as the below code literally kills (slows down to beyond of unresponsiveness) Safari browser. Works kind of OK in Chrome and Firefox. Though, I do see memory utilization increases with every click but not as much as in Safari.

```
$('#calculate').click(function() {

var a_length = $("#a_length").slider('value');
var a_width = $("#a_width").slider('value');
var b_length = $("#b_length").slider('value');
var b_width = $("#b_width").slider('value');
var b_length2 = $("#b_length2").slider('value');
var b_width2 = $("#b_width2").slider('value');

var data_expert = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

data_expert.push({name: 'a_length', value: a_length});
data_expert.push({name: 'a_width', value: a_width});
data_expert.push({name: 'b_length', value: b_length});
data_expert.push({name: 'b_width', value: b_width});
data_expert.push({name: 'b_length2', value: b_length2});
data_expert.push({name: 'b_width2', value: b_width2});

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"myurl",
    data:data_expert,
    cache: false,
    success:function(html)
    {
        $("#calc_result").hide();
        $("#calc_result").html(html).fadeIn("slow");

        $("#refresh-area-a").load(location.href + " #price-a");
        $("#refresh-area-b").load(location.href + " #price-b");

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');

        googletag.cmd.push(googletag.pubads().refresh());
        googletag.pubads().refresh();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Should `googletag.cmd.push(googletag.pubads().refresh())` instead be `googletag.cmd.push(googletag.pubads().refresh)`? (Note lack of `()` at the end.) I don't know that API but it looks like it's expecting a function.

Comment: It has to be refresh(). However, it's definitely googletag stuff that is causing memory leak (commenting refresh out - no memory issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
googletag.pubads().refresh();return false;
```